# Python exec and __name__

Tags: python, scope, exec

When I run:

```
exec("print(__name__)")
```

it prints `__main__`.

But when I run:

```
exec("print __name__", {})
```

it prints `builtins`.

How to make the second example to also print `__main__`?

What I try to achieve is to run a piece of code with `exec()` so that from the perspective of the it looks like it was run from command line.

I would like to tun the code with clean scope but the second example breaks the code relying on `if __name__ == "__main__"`. How to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`imp.load_module`](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html#imp.load_module) instead:

```
import imp

with open(mainfile) as src:
    imp.load_module('__main__', src, mainfile, (".py", "r", imp.PY_SOURCE))
```

This imports the file as the `__main__` module, executing it.

Note that it takes an actual file object when the type is set to `imp.PY_SOURCE`, so you'd need to create a temporary file for this to work if your source code comes from somewhere other than a file.

Otherwise, can always set `__name__` manually:

```
>>> src = '''\
... if __name__ == '__main__': print('Main!')
... else: print('Damn', __name__)
... '''
>>> exec(src)
Main!
>>> exec(src, {})
Damn builtins
>>> exec(src, {'__name__':'__main__'})
Main!
```

Comment: I cannot unfortunately create a temporary file on disk. Isn't there a way to execute plain string as if it was run from command line? And one more question about your reply: it looks like it as if it was importing (as in `import`) the file - does it import or execute the file? Is there a difference?

Comment: In order to import a module, it *has* to be executed.

Comment: Note that the expectation that `__name__ == '__main__'` works implies you are executing modules here.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your last comment - what do you mean by "here"? The `src` string? And I have to ask similar question as for the other answer - is `in {'__name__':'__main__'}` enough to make `src` believe it was executed from command line? I mean are there any traps I should know about? If it is enough though that would make it for a perfect solution, thanks in any case...

Comment: One last question, the docs say `exec expr in globals, locals` - should I put `{'__name__':'__main__'}` in globals or locals? `exec src in {'__name__':'__main__'}` or `exec src in {}, {'__name__':'__main__'}`

Comment: 'here' as in your question. `__name__` is a module global, in modules globals and locals *are the same thing* so you should *not* supply a locals mapping. Testing for `__name__` is the defacto way to test if this is the main script, setting it is enough.

Comment: Is this answer still valid for Python 3, or what needs to be updated? (or where is the appropriate existing Q&A for Python 3?)

Comment: @mkrieger1: you could have tried it? It's still applicable to Python 3. I've updated the syntax here and in the question to use Python 3 compatible `exec()` and `print()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to provide the `__name__` explicitly in your `exec`ution dict:

```
exec("print(__name__)", {'__name__': '__main__'})
```

Comment: Is it safe? I mean is the only difference between the code from question and running the code from command line only this fix? I know there are more keys like `__doc__` but is this fix essential to making it look like code from command line?